# smartphone acceleration sensor max value to calculate swing power

Tags: android

I am working an smartphone acceleration sensor to calculate swing intensity.
In Android galaxy nexus, the maximum value of X, Y, Z is about 20.
So I don't use this value for swing motion of smartphone.
The maximum value of acceleration is limited to me.
I want to have more big value for checking.
Now, powerful swing 19.xx ...  normal swing 19.xx ... not distinct

Comment: Does this actually have to do with [swing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swing)?

Comment: Check the plausibility of your numbers.  What sort of centripetal acceleration do you read for slower swing?  If you set the phone on the table in all 6 cardinal orientations, what do you read on the gravity-aligned, vs. other axis?  what about at a 45% angle between two of them?